# How to deserialize a MediaWiki API Result C#

Tags: c#, json

I'm trying to deserialize this json response: https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&search=zyz&limit=1&namespace=0&format=jsonfm

I am not exactly sure what my C# object should look like when I deserialize this. This is what I have at the moment:

```
public class test
    {
        public string search { get; set; }
        public List<string> title = new List<string>();
        public List<string> uk = new List<string>();
        public List<string> link = new List<string>();
    }
```

When I try to deserialize it into this object I get an exception.
Could anyone help me out?

Comment: Did you check their documentation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can deserialize it as a dynamic object and then access the elements which are nothing more than an array of objects (objects including strings and array of strings.)

**input string**

```
 ["zyz",["Zyzzyx Road"],[""],["https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zyzzyx_Road"]]
```

**Deserialize**

```
    var res = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(json);

    // To Access the values which are either strings or array of strings, 
    Console.WriteLine(res[0].Value);
    Console.WriteLine(res[1][0].Value);
    Console.WriteLine(res[2][0].Value);
    Console.WriteLine(res[3][0].Value);
```

**Output**

```
zyz
Zyzzyx Road

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zyzzyx_Road
```

Comment: It's pretty neat to deserialize to `dynamic`, never seen this before.

Answer (score 0):

Okay first up your uri, if you open that it tells you that it is not the correct format. Therefor you should use this one instead `https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&search=zyz&limit=1&namespace=0&format=json`.

Next up, there are a few websites which exactly do to that.

- [json2csharp](http://json2csharp.com/)
- [quicktype](https://app.quicktype.io/)

Anyhow you would need to do a lot of funky stuff, since this api returns really weird json.

Anyhow there are people who already did that like [WikipediaNet](https://github.com/Genbox/WikipediaNet), which makes it a lot simpler.

Comment: My code successfully gets a response, with content "[\"zyz\",[\"Zyzzyx Road\"],[\"\"],[\"https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zyzzyx_Road\"]]". I'll look into that wikipedianet!

Comment: @bougiemane well then it looks like you referenced a wrong uri.

Comment: That wikipedianet is exactly what I needed, thanks for your help!

Comment: @bougiemane if this helped you, feel free to mark it as the answer so other people will find it quicker :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are not keen to use Wikipedianet, then you could create a method to parse results as following.

```
public IEnumerable<Result> GetResult(string json)
{
    var parsedResult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<dynamic>>(json);

    if(parsedResult.OfType<JArray>().Any()) 
    {
        for(var i=0;i<parsedResult.OfType<JArray>().First().Count();i++)
        {
            var returnValue = new Result();
            returnValue.SearchTerm = parsedResult.First();
            returnValue.Key = parsedResult.Skip(1).First()[i].Value;
            returnValue.Description = parsedResult.Skip(2).First()[i].Value;
            returnValue.Url = parsedResult.Skip(3).First()[i].Value;
            yield return returnValue;
        }
    }
    else
        yield return null;
}
```

Where Result is defined as

```
public class Result
{
    public string SearchTerm{get;set;}
    public string Key{get;set;}
    public string Description{get;set;}
    public string Url{get;set;}
}
```

**Output**

[image]

This might be useful when you have more than one result in the Json (when url parameter `limit` set to more than 1)